# Django's get_current_language always returns "en"

Tags: django, localization, django-templates, internationalization

In my Django 2.0 site, I want to set the `lang` atribute of the html tag to the current locale's language. In my `base.html` which other templates extend, I use [`get_current_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) in the following way

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
 ...
</html>
```

The site has translations for multiple languages. If I switch the language in the browser, I see the correct translations, but the `lang` attribute will always contain `en`.

In my `settings.py` I have

```
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
```

and based on the suggestion of [Goran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928017/goran) the following middleware order

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]
```

The `LANGUAGES` setting is unset.

As suggested by [Kostadin Slavov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340867/kostadin-slavov) I have tried printing the language from the view. It seems that get_current_language calls django.utils.translation.get_language, so I have inserted the following in my view

```
from django.utils import translation                                        
print(translation.get_language())
```

It prints the correct value (eg `de` when accessing the view with a browser set to German).

What else am I missing?

Comment: be sure that the order of middlewares is correct [how Django discovers language preferences](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

Comment: I've fixed the order of middlewares according to the docs; it didn't fix the problem, but I've added the information to the question above.

Comment: are you sure that you send POST request to the `{% url 'set_language' %}`? The view expects to be called via the POST method [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view)

Comment: No, I am sending an Accept-Language header. It is enough for the translations to work correctly.

Comment: What do you have set for LANGUAGE_CODE and LANGUAGES, if anything?

Comment: Hi, @StefanKögl, what is the value of {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}  try printing it out in the backend to see what is sending to you

Comment: I have added the requested info within the question.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to simulate your environment with these steps:

```
$ cd ~
$ python3 -m venv ~/venvs/mysite
$ source ~/venvs/mysite/bin/activate
$ pip install django==2.0.8
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

Then I updated the generate code as in your example:

- mysite/settings.py

  ```
  ...
  MIDDLEWARE = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  ]
  ...
  TEMPLATES = [
      {
          'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
          'DIRS': ['templates'],
          'APP_DIRS': True,
          'OPTIONS': {
              'context_processors': [
                  'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                  'django.template.context_processors.request',
                  'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                  'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
              ],
          },
      },
  ]
  ...
  ```
- mysite/urls.py

  ```
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.urls import path
  from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

  urlpatterns = [
      path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='home'),
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  ]
  ```
- templates/base.html

  ```
  {% load i18n %}
  {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
  <body>
  <pre>LANGUAGE_CODE = {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</pre>
  <body>
  </html>
  ```

With the Django generated code and my few above updates I can see different language code if I switch the language of my browser visiting http://localhost:8000/ after starting it with:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Try my steps on your local environment and check if it works, and then compare your project to the code above.

## Update

Try to use [diffsettings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#diffsettings) to see "differences between the current settings file and Django’s default settings".

Comment: A simple project like this works correctly; however the issue is the comparison of my project to one like this. I am not sure what I could miss that is causing the wrong language to be returned.

Comment: So have you tried my simple test locally? Can you provide more details about your project to permit recreate your environment ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I also setup a simple project, tested against 2.0 and 2.1, and found that both versions worked as expected. I was able to reproduce the default (en-us) if I had LANGUAGES defined to an empty list.

Comment: I can't see your code but I would check the diff of settings and try to use only defaults adding your settings one by one to see which setting broke the language tag.

Comment: Can I use get_current_language without using LocaleMiddleware? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301978/djangos-get-current-language-strange-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case, the function was called async and always returned the default language.

SOLUTION: pass language from 'main' context.

Code like in this example:

```
def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    lng_code = get_language() # -> 'de'

    @sync_to_async
    def get_data():

        context['data1'] = Model1.objects.filter(language==get_language()) # get_language() -> 'en'

    @sync_to_async
    def get_data2():
        ...

    @sync_to_async
    def get_data3():
        ...

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                    get_data1(),
                    get_data2(),
                    get_data3()
                    ))
    loop.close()
```