# Django's get_current_language strange behavior

Tags: django, django-i18n

I want to set the lang attribute in my html tag to the current locale's language based on the language defined in my settings.py. I don't use the LocaleMiddleware and the user can not choose the language.

(I have different domain's for the same page. If someone want's to see the website in a different language, the user has to go to a different website )

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-PL'
USE_I18N      = True
USE_L10N      = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('de', 'German'),
    ('pl', 'Polish'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
]
```

**Django version**

Django==2.0.9

**Template**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
```

**Output**

If I refresh the page without interacting I got sometimes:

- pl
- pl-pl
- pl-PL

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `{{ lang.code }}` to get only `pl` part (it depends on language).

---

In this case Django gets user language preference from **Accept-Language** HTTP header, which usually contains several language codes, with priority.

It may contain multiple language-codes for one base language, depending on your system locale, browser settings, etc; i.e. **pl-PL,pl-pl,pl;q=0.7** where *q* is priority.

Django parses header and sorts language codes based on priority. Since priority is the same for several codes - they will appear in different order in the result for each request and the first one will be used.

Comment: Ahh okay, so in my case I shouldn't use it at all. I wrote my own context_process which is just adding LANGUAGE_CODE from the settings directly.